# Using __contains__ method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using ____contains__ method in python as per below:

Case 1: True

```
if ('A','B','D').__contains__('A'or'E'):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Case 2: False

```
if ('A','B','D').__contains__('E'or'B'):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

If I replace **or** with **and**, that works and also using expressions such as (('E' and 'A') and ('B' and 'C')) works.

Please could you confirm why **or** does not work in standard way like if I were to do something like if (B or C) condition? Also is there other ways of doing the above using regular expressions or lamda expressions?

Comment: `or` **is** working in the standard way. Have you seen what `'E' or 'B'` evaluates to? For that matter, `'E' and 'B'`? Any debugging at all? Also, **why are you using `__contains__`** directly? You shouldn't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **and** and **or** incorrectly.

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned. // 
>   https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Also, double underscore functions are marked with the double underscore especially as a marker that people *shouldn't usually use them*.

**(One of the) correct ways to write the above is:**

```
my_tuple=('A','B','D')
if 'A' in my_tuple or 'E' in my_tuple:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: Also note, if the things to test are large (so typing `or ... X in my_tuple` over and over is a pain), you can generalize to many item case with `any`, e.g. in this case, you *could* do `if any(x in my_tuple for x in ('A', 'B')):`; adding new items to check for just means expanding the `tuple` being iterated. Alternatively, `set` operations can help if the types are hashable, e.g. `if not {'A', 'E'}.isdisjoint(my_tuple):`, especially if one side or the other can be converted to `set` once up front and reused for many tests.

Comment: thank you for your replies. What if there is an expression such as  (A or E) and B? I wouldn't be able to use any.. The expressions can change so no consistent pattern.

Comment: @user5711693 if you have to allow for arbitrary combinations you would probably need to build some parser, using, eg pyparsing module. If your source of combinations is some text input. This is however completely outside the scope of the original question. You will need to ask another one, preferably with enough detail as to what exactly you are trying to achieve. Note, however, that it is usually expected you only ask after getting some general understanding of the topic itself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `__contains__` like that. Use `in` like this.

```py
if ('A' or 'E') in ('A', 'B', 'C'):
    pass
```

Hopefully this will start to show where your problem is. The `a or b` is evaluating before the `__contains__` is being called and only one of the values is being tested for inclusion.

The statement `('A' or 'E')` will simplify to `'A'`. That is why your first case is printing `True`.

```py
if ('E' or 'B') in ('A', 'B', 'C'):
    pass
```

For your second case `('E' or 'B')` will evaluate to `'E'`, which isn't in `('A', 'B', 'C')`, so your second case prints `False`.

**Addendum**

To correct this code you should be thinking a little bit more verbosely.

```py
values = ('A', 'B', 'C')

if 'A' in values or 'E' in values:
    pass

if 'E' in values or 'B' in values:
    pass
```

Comment: You say "Use `in` like this", but still show the wrong way to use it. Showing only wrong ways to perform the test, with no corrected ways, is going to confuse folks who don't read too closely.

Comment: The code that I wrote out doesn't actually change your logic (which does need to be changed). I only addressed the syntactical improprieties in the code blocks. What @ShadowRanger is saying is that my answer is confusing because I don't show corrected logic, I only talk about it around the code blocks.